# Error: Image.date: Image does not have a 'system:time_start' property. (Error code: 3)

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to export the random forest sorted points to a table, here is my code.

```
// Define a function to generate the quality mask for remote sensing images
var qualityMask = function(im) {
  return im
    .updateMask(im.select('quality_flag').eq(1))
    .updateMask(im.select('degrade_flag').eq(0))
    .updateMask(im.select('rh25').gte(3)); // Filter out GEDI data below 3 meters
};

// Input the study area
var Bound = ee.FeatureCollection(table);

// Select the GEDI dataset, filter by date (2019-2021), apply quality mask, select image bands, calculate the median
var dataset1 = ee.ImageCollection('LARSE/GEDI/GEDI02_A_002_MONTHLY')
  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-12-30')
  .map(qualityMask)
  .select('rh95')
  .median();

// Clip the GEDI dataset to the study area
var clipped = dataset1.clipToCollection(Bound);

// Define the visualization parameters for GEDI data
var gediVis = {
  min: 1,
  max: 60,
  palette: 'darkred,red,orange,green,darkgreen',
};

// Convert the dataset type to integer
var sample = clipped.toInt();

// Vectorize the GEDI data
var vector = sample.reduceToVectors({
  geometry: Bound,
  crs: sample.projection(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
});

// Limit the number of vectors
var vectors = vector.limit(3500);
print(vectors);

// Select the Landsat 8 dataset, filter by date (2019-2021), filter by cloud cover less than 20%, calculate the median
var Landsat8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-12-30')
  .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 20)
  .median();

// Set the 'system:time_start' property to the start date of the Landsat 8 collection
var startDate = ee.Date('2019-01-01');
var Landsat8ImageWithTime = Landsat8.set('system:time_start', startDate.millis());

// Clip the Landsat 8 dataset to the study area
var L8 = Landsat8ImageWithTime.clipToCollection(Bound);
print(L8);

// Define the NDVI function
function NDVI(img) {
  var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(["SR_B5", "SR_B4"]);
  var min = ndvi.reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
  var max = ndvi.reduce(ee.Reducer.max());
  var q1 = ndvi.reduce(ee.Reducer.percentile([25]));
  var q3 = ndvi.reduce(ee.Reducer.percentile([75]));
  var avg1 = ndvi.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).where(ndvi.lt(q1), min);
  var avg2 = ndvi.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).where(ndvi.gt(q3), max);
  var amp1 = max.subtract(min);
  var amp2 = q3.subtract(q1);
  return ndvi
    .addBands(min)
    .addBands(max)
    .addBands(avg1)
    .addBands(avg2)
    .addBands(amp1)
    .addBands(amp2);
}

// Calculate the NDVI index
var ndvi = NDVI(L8);

// Select the SRTM global elevation dataset and clip it to the study area
var dataset2 = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003').clip(Bound);

// Calculate terrain parameters
var terrain = ee.Algorithms.Terrain(dataset2);
var elevation = terrain.select('elevation');
var slope = terrain.select('slope');
var aspect = terrain.select('aspect');

// Select band B6 of Landsat 8 dataset
var L8_B6 = L8.select('SR_B6');

// Add terrain parameters, NDVI index, and NDVI-related bands to Landsat 8 dataset
var L8_RF = L8_B6
  .addBands(elevation.rename('elevation').toFloat())
  .addBands(ndvi.select('nd').rename('ndvi').toFloat())
  .addBands(aspect.rename('aspect').toFloat())
  .addBands(slope.rename('slope').toFloat())
  .addBands(ndvi.select('min').rename('ndvi').toFloat())
  .addBands(ndvi.select('max').rename('ndvi').toFloat())
  .addBands(ndvi.select('mean').rename('ndvi').toFloat())
  .addBands(ndvi.select('mean_1').rename('ndvi').toFloat())
  .addBands(ndvi.select('max_1').rename('ndvi').toFloat())
  .addBands(ndvi.select('p75').rename('ndvi').toFloat());

// Get the band names of Landsat 8 dataset
var bands = L8_RF.bandNames();

// Sample the pixels of Landsat 8 dataset and merge the samples with vector data
var samples = L8_RF.sampleRegions({
  collection: vectors,
  properties: ['label'],
  scale: 30,
  tileScale: 16,
});

// Filter out samples with labels less than or equal to 3
var aspenSites = samples.filterMetadata({ name: "label", operator: "greater_than", value: 3 });

// Add a random column to the samples
var withRandom = aspenSites.randomColumn('random');

// Split the samples into training and testing partitions
var split = 0.7;
var trainingPartition = withRandom.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', split));
var testingPartition = withRandom.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random', split));

// Train a random forest classifier
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(300)
  .train({
    features: trainingPartition,
    classProperty: 'label',
    inputProperties: bands,
  });

// Classify the Landsat 8 dataset
var classified = L8_RF.classify(classifier, 'predicted');

var ft = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List([]));

// Define a function to fill the feature collection with classified samples
var fill = function(img, ini) {
  var inift = ee.FeatureCollection(ini)
  var ft2 = img.sampleRegions({
  collection:Bound,
  properties:ee.List(['label']),
  //scale:30
  });
  var date = img.date().format()
  var ft3 = ft2.map(function(f){return f.set("date", date)})
  return inift.merge(ft3)
};

// Fill the feature collection with classified samples
var newft = ee.FeatureCollection(fill(classified, ft));

// Export the feature collection to Google Drive as a CSV file
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: newft,
  description: 'sample_get3',
  fileFormat: 'CSV',
});
```

Here is my link:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/fb49f28e9079d507dc3ac20b3a3a543b